# Colour specific functions in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting

I have a few functions I use for debugging in eclipse.

I would like to be able to highlight these functions. Is there a user defined list I can say I want `MyUtils.myFunction(...blarblar...)` to be pink or something? Even if it is just the `MyUtils.myFunction` part.

Or possibly an annotated tag on the function itself? Though being IDE side rather than something within the code would be nicer.

I would like these functions to be **HYPER** visible all the time. Without having to so a search.

Multiple functions would be beneficial, but if any solution is limited to 1, I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in coloring option like that, but you could probably use [Bookmarks](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-37-3b.htm?cp=0_1_0_13) as an alternative. From the help docs:

> Bookmarks are a simple way to navigate to resources that are used frequently.

Comment: It's not for jumping to the debug function. It's for making it very obvious it is there within hundreds of lines of code. Want to be able to see at a super fast glance as I am scrolling quickly through the file debugging code/functions. It currently gets lost in a sea of lines. Kinda like a permanent  set of "mark occurrences" that happen to be a certain colour.